# Solving a differential equation using substitution $y=zt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I've just started taking a course in differential equations and encountered the following question:

> Solve the differential equation $tyy'=2y^2-t^2$

The hint was to use the substitution $y=zt$. First I divided by $ty$, and got the equation:$$y'=\frac{2y}{t}-\frac{t}{y}$$Using this substitution I can rewrite $y'$ as: $$y'=z't+z$$ and therefore the equation becomes: $$z't+z=2z-\frac{1}{z}\Rightarrow z'=(z-\frac{1}{z})\frac{1}{t}$$ which is seperable.
Integrating both sides w.r.t to $t$, I got that: $$\frac{1}{2}\ln|z^2-1|=\ln|t|+C$$. Now I'm stuck cause I don't know how to get rid of the absolute value. How do I get rid of it in general? do I just write two solutions $y_1,y_2$ or is there a smarter way?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could also just compute the derivative $(y^2/t^4)'$ and compare with the given equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a standard trick.  When you exponentiate both sides, you end up with an $e^C$ multiplied on the right.  You can change the absolute values to $\pm$ then you have something like

$$\pm(y^2-1) = e^c(\pm t).$$

So, first, there's no reason for both $\pm$'s.  Second, that $e^c$ is just an arbitrary (and positive) constant, so replace it with $A$:

$$(y^2-1) = \pm At.$$

Then just realize that $\pm A$ where $A$ is positive and arbitrary is the same as just having $A$ and allowing it to be negative too.  So you can let the arbitrary constant "absorb" the $\pm.$

Comment: Is it possible to multiply both sides of the equation by $1/2$ and then have: $\ln|z^2-1|=\ln(t^2)+2c$ and then do the standard trick?

Comment: @GBA  Yes.  That's probably the best way to go.